# Explain the mechanism of glycerol solubility in ether.?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I need some guidance regarding the issue of solubility, as you can see in my question i have glycerol and ether.

What factors play a role in the solubilization process between these two compounds?

I know that glycerol has polar character and intermolecular dipole-dipole forces, while ether (ethyl ether, i imagine) has less polar character than glycerol and Hydrogen bonding type intermolecular forces. But how can this type of solubility originate taking into account these aspects?

Excuse me for my English.

Thanks a lot...

Comment: Well water is soluble in diethyl ether (6.05g per 100ml at 25C)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to a 1951 article in J. Am. Chem. Soc., water is soluble in diethyl ether to the extent of 1.468%, although other investigators had found between 1.19 and 2.66%. https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja01150a531 And the solubility of ether in water is about the same.

Water and glycerol are completely miscible - no insolubility at all.

According to the CRC Handbook, glycerol and diethyl ether are immiscible. Of course, water and ether are also immiscible, but there is some slight solubility, so you might expect similar solubility between ether and glycerol. Rather than explain tiny solubilities, the immiscibility reaction suggests that the two compounds are just too different to be compatible.

While water is a good example of hydrogen-bonded molecules rejecting the less polar ether molecules, I see glycerol, a viscous group of hydrogen-bonded molecules just not opening up to let an ether molecule in. And ether is so non-polar that it doesn't even stick to itself very well (i.e., it's quite volatile), so instead of associating with glycerol, it vaporizes and leaves the system quickly.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Everything makes sense now, your explanation was very helpful to me to understand this case.

Comment: I love the downvote! The answer is acceptable to the OP, but not to some browser. I guess Einstein was right: "All problems should be solved as simply as possible, but not simpler." (Unless maybe you are a beginner.)